# How to use dictionary yielded from other solid in a composite Solid?

Tags: python, dagster

For example I have a solid named **initiate_load** , it is yielding a **dictionary** and an **integer** , something like :

```py
@solid(
    output_defs=[
        OutputDefinition(name='l_dict', is_required=False),
        OutputDefinition(name='l_int', is_required=False)
    ],
)
def initiate_load(context):
    .... 
    ....

    yield Output(l_dict, output_name='l_dict')
    yield Output(l_int, output_name='l_int')
```

I have a composite_solid also ,let's say  **call_other_solid_composite**

and I am passing `l_dict` and `l_int`  to this `composite_solid`
and I am using the `l_dict` to get the values mapped to its keys. Something like.

```py
@composite_solid
def call_other_solid_composite(p_dict,p_int):
    l_val1 = p_dict['val1']
    ...
    ...
```

Then I am getting a Error as :`TypeError: 'InputMappingNode' object is not subscriptable`.
I searched everywhere but can't find a solution . The documentation is also of no help . I have use case that I need to parse those values .
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to methods decorated with @pipeline, you should not think of methods decorated with @composite_solid as regular python methods. Dagster will wrap them and make it something completely different. That's why the `p_dict` parameter cannot be used inside the method as a regular method parameter.

To achieve what you want, you have a couple of options:

- pass the `p_dict` parameter directly in another solid and inside this solid you will be able to do `l_val1 = p_dict['val1']`
- next to the yields you now have in the `initiate_load` method, you can yield `p_dict['val1']` as an output as well. This allows you to use both the dict and the 'val1' value as inputs in other solids (also in your composite)
- you can have a solid in your composite solid that yields the `p_dict['val1']`, this allows you to use this value as an input for other solids inside the composite.

Hope this helps. For reference, the documentation about the composite solids can be found [here](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/solids#composing-solids).

A small remark on the snippets you provided. Dagster has a very neat typing system, it is best practice to use this as much as possible.

Comment: I know the difference between the method and a solid. But unfortunately, my use-case doesn't allow me to introduce one more solid or yield the output. Had to switch to a normal solid and inside the solid, we are now calling a ThreadPooling to execute things in parallel.  The snippet was just to keep things as simple as possible so that it doesn't confuse others. I do use typing. But, I really feel the documentation needs to be improved for Dagster .